# How to access state of one slice in reducer of another slice using redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to access state of another slice in reducer of another slice using getState() method but looks like this is not allowed and hence the web application breaks.

Does anyone know whats the recommended way to access state of a slice inside reducer of another slice? I need this for my web application.

Thanks in advance for your any help

Answer (score 15):

According to the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers), there are 3 different approaches you could use:

> Many users later want to try to share data between two reducers, but
> find that combineReducers does not allow them to do so. There are
> several approaches that can be used:
>
> 1. If a reducer needs to know data from another slice of state, the state
>    tree shape may need to be reorganized so that a single reducer is
>    handling more of the data.
> 2. You may need to write some custom functions
>    for handling some of these actions. This may require replacing
>    combineReducers with your own top-level reducer function. You can also
>    use a utility such as reduce-reducers to run combineReducers to handle
>    most actions, but also run a more specialized reducer for specific
>    actions that cross state slices.
> 3. Middleware with async logic such as
>    redux-thunk have access to the entire state through getState(). An
>    action creator can retrieve additional data from the state and put it
>    in an action, so that each reducer has enough information to update
>    its own state slice.

**Example**

Lets assume we have the following slices:

```
const namesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Names",
  initialState: {
    value: [],
    name: "Names"
  },
  reducers: {
    ...
  }
};

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Counter",
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
    name: "Names"
  },
  reducers: {
    ...
  }
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer,
  names: namesReducer
});
```

And we want to define an action `addName` which will add a name (entered by the user) into the `names` array, but will also append the current value of the `counter` state onto the name before adding it.

**Option 1: Restructure Slices**

This involves merging the 2 slices into a single slice, so you'd end up with something like:

```
const namesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "NamesAndCounter",
  initialState: {
    value: {
      names: [],
      counter: 0
    },
    name: "NamesAndCounter"
  },
  ...
};
```

which would allow you to access both `names` and `counter` in the reducer.

If you don't want to restructure your state/slices, then there are options 2 and 3:

**Option 2: Use reduce-reducers**

A third party library [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/redux-utilities/reduce-reducers) can be used

Here you would define a cross slice reducer which is capable of accessing both the `counter` and `names` slices:

```
export const crossSliceReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "CROSS_SLICE_ACTION") {
    const newName = action.payload + state.counter.value;
    const namesState = state.names;
    state = {
      ...state,
      names: { ...namesState, value: [...state.names.value, newName] }
    };
  }
  return state;
};

// Combine reducers
const reducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer,
  names: namesReducer
});

// Add the cross-slice reducer to the root reducer
const rootReducer = reduceReducers(reducer, crossSliceReducer);

// Create store
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
});
```

Then you can dispatch the following action to invoke the reducer:

```
dispatch({ type: "CROSS_SLICE_ACTION", payload: name });
```

**Note:** The `reduce-reducers` library is [no longer being maintained](https://github.com/redux-utilities/reduce-reducers#looking-for-maintainers)

**Option 3: Use Thunks**

Using thunks (meant for async actions like calling an API) allows you to get at the entire state. You can define a thunk that references the `getState` function that allows you to get at any slice in the global state:

```
export const addWithThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  "names/addWithThunk",
  async (name, { getState }) => {
    return name + getState().counter.value;
  }
);
```

Thunks are defined in the `extraReducers` property of the argument passed to `createSlice()`:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(addWithThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.value.push(action.payload);
    });
  }
```

And can be invoked in the same way you'd invoke a plain action:

```
dispatch(addWithThunk(name));
```

There's a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-example-forked-bof39g?file=/src/App.js) showing options 2 and 3. When you add a name using one of the `Submit` buttons, it will access the `counter` state and append the current value of the counter to the name you input before adding the name into the `names` state.

Comment: If I could I would upvote this twice! Thank you!